# Why the tar file is not the same size on Ubuntu and the VM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compression, virtual-machine, tar

I executed the same script that will generate a .tgz file on a Ubuntu VM running on Windows7 and on a different computer with only Ubuntu installed on it.

I compared the tgz file generated by my linux computer and the VM, and the file generated is about 1MB bigger on the VM.

But, when I untar the file, all the files in the tgz have exactly the same size on both systems.

I added below all the information I could think about that could help anybody to figure why the .tgz is not the same size on both system.

Info about VM:

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 32BITS

Release 12.4

Codename precise

tar version: 1.27.1

Info about Linux Computer:

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64BITS

Release 14.4

Codename trusty

tar version: 1.27.1

The only difference between the two computers is the OS installed, they are the same model, with same configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: If the VM is constrained on memory, gzip will not be able to compress as much.  (gzip does not use a *lot*, like other methods, but still...).

Answer (score 0):

The different versions of the OS, libraries and/or the tar/gz executables or, as @ThomasDickey mentioned - the context in which the archives are created can all cause the actual content of the archive file to be different.

If you want to know for sure if the file contents are identical just copy one of them side-by-side with the other and diff them.

Even with the exact same file contents the actual file sizes can also differ due to differences in the filesystem type, version, formatting options, (maybe even fragmentation?) etc.

If you have side-by-side copies they *should* have the same size (unless fragmentation is involved).